# Can't create DB in migration of a .NET Core app using CleanArchitecture

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, clean-architecture

I try to follow the link
https://www.ezzylearning.net/tutorial/building-asp-net-core-apps-with-clean-architecture

And this Github at: https://github.com/ezzylearning/CleanArchitectureDemo

To learn more about clean architecture. I have created a project solution at https://github.com/nguyentuananh921/AJAX/

But when I run `add-migration`, I get an error like this:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Persistence.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Persistence.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I have tried to review but I can't find the error. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I clone your project from GitHub and test it, Successfully `add-migration/update-database` and create database. You can follow these steps:

Set your APi project as startup project.

install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` in your `CleanArchitectureDemo.Persistence` project.

In Package Manager Console set `CleanArchitectureDemo.Persistence` as default project.

[image]

Finally `add-migration/update-database` then create database successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you had uploaded an image, it could have been better, but did you check again these steps:
1- DbContext Configuration, ensure that your DbContext class in this case, (ApplicationDbContext) is correctly configured for dependency injection in your startup class.
2- check that your connection string in the appsettings.json
3- Ensure that your ApplicationDbContext class has a constructor that accepts DbContextOptions
4- If you're using SQL Server, you should have the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package installed.
5- Make sure there are no other errors in your Startup.cs class or other parts of the application
6- Did you try cleaning and Rebuilding?

Comment: I am also upload code to github for more investigation.

In the Persistence Project I also have ApplicationDbContext. It inherit from DbContext and It also have constructor


1. I also check and register it in namespace Persistence. 

2. I want to use WebMVC as a presentation layer so in appsettings.json
I also have Connectionstring.

3. And In Program.cs I also add service from other layer.
I also have clean solution and rebuild the solution without any error but I can't migrate and create Database.
Please investigate and help me.THanks.